# Sprite Kit App Crash on SKCAction::wasRemovedFromTarget

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skaction

I have tested my app thoroughly on my device with no crashes, the game runs great. However, on my friends device and a few others, it is crashing at the same point. After running the app on my friends device I get this exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, with no error message in the console. And my call stack is the screenshot I attached below:

Why is this happening on one device, but not others? Perhaps it's because of different iOS versions but I would like to solve this.

[image]

Also, here is the code I am running:

I create an SKAction to resuse. This action shoots razors across the screen for you to dodge it. It always seems to crash either 2-3 razors in..

SKAction Creation:

```
 CGFloat distanceToMoveArrow = self.frame.size.width + (_razorTexture.size.width*4);
SKAction* moveArrow = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMoveArrow y:0 duration:0.001 * distanceToMoveArrow];
SKAction* removeArrow = [SKAction removeFromParent];
_moveAndRemoveArrow = [SKAction sequence:@[moveArrow, removeArrow]];
```

Shooting the Razors:

```
 NSLog(@"Arrow Shot");

SKNode* razorGroup = [SKNode node];
razorGroup.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + _razorTexture.size.width, 0 );

SKSpriteNode* razor = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_razorTexture];
razor.position = CGPointMake( 0, _bird.position.y);
razor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_razorTexture.size.width/2];
razor.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
razor.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
razor.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory;
[razorGroup addChild:razor];

[razorGroup runAction:_moveAndRemoveArrow];
[_obstacles addChild:razorGroup];

[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"razor-sound.wav" waitForCompletion:NO] withKey:@"RazorSound"];
```

FYI - This seems to only be happening on iOS 7

Comment: The screenshot you posted isn't a call stack / stack trace. Please post a full symbolicated stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, can you help me..how do I do this? @AaronBrager

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @AaronBrager I've updated my question..is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"razor-sound.wav" waitForCompletion:NO] withKey:@"RazorSound"];
```

It was running multiple at the same time, so after I removed the 'withKey' it all worked perfectly.. Must be a weird bug in iOS 7.

Comment: I don't believe it is actually a bug if `self` is your scene. What is happening is you are trying to run an action over and over again with the same key before the previous is finished. If you think about what '[self actionForKey:@"RazorSound"];' would return if you ran three actions with the same key it kind of makes sense. If `self` isn't your scene but instead a separate SKNode then ignore everything I said =)